# Multidimensional array from JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

*** Code updated after recommendation **

Hi,
I'm trying to parse a multidimensional array from json on my Android Project... I have read a lot of codes from other questions in stackoverflow but i can't understand very well how it works...

this is my JSON file:

http://pastebin.com/Vf4xWanC

and here is my code:

```
public String[][] parseJSON_canales() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        enfrentan = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ENFRENTAMIENTOS);
        canales_recv = new String[enfrentan.length()][];

        for (int i = 0; i < enfrentan.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = enfrentan.getJSONObject(i);
            todosCanales = jo.getJSONArray(JSON_CANALES);
            for (int j = 0; j < todosCanales.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject jo1 = todosCanales.getJSONObject(j);
                canales_recv[i][j] = jo1.getString(CANALES_OBTENIDOS);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception: " + e.getCause());
        Log.e("MYAPP", "exception: " + e.toString());
    }
    return canales_recv;
}
```

I need to get "emite" values inside "equpos" array , any idea from what i'm doing bad?

Comment: canales_recv[i][j] = jo.getString(CANALES_OBTENIDOS); // change jo to jo1

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved, and to offer details about the answer. To do so, please make a self-answer below, so that the original state of the question can be maintained. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems alright. BUT you are returning an empty String[][]

```
return new String[0][0];
```

you should return your "canales_recv" instead

```
return canales_recv;
```

And also as the comment said

```
canales_recv[i][j] = jo.getString(CANALES_OBTENIDOS); // change jo to jo1
```

Comment: In first place, thank you for your quickly response and help... I have made changes, but I get this error: 06-06 13:24:50.981 13661-13661/in.arenadroid.arenavision W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

Comment: can you please put a log before this line and check if there is any value  canales_recv = new String[enfrentan.length()][];

Comment: Printing canales_recv.length:  06-06 13:33:47.228 17995-17995/in.arenadroid.arenavision I/System.out: MYAPP: canales_recv: 3 and LOG: http://pastebin.com/vdda67PS

Comment: which one is the line no : 61

Comment: canales_recv[i][j] = jo1.getString(CANALES_OBTENIDOS);

Comment: I think that I have found something... I print the value of "i" before "canales_recv[i][j] = jo1.getString(CANALES_OBTENIDOS);" and surprise i = 0, can it help you?

Comment: todosCanales = jo.getJSONArray(JSON_CANALES);
                canales_recv[i] = new String[todosCanales.length()];  // add this line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113918/discussion-between-lomunet-arratiko-and-godslave-asad).